# Timer overflow race condition

Tags: timer, overflow, microcontroller

I am using a micro controller with a 16 bit timer counting up. The current value can be read from a register. However I need a 32 bit counter. Every time the timer overflows, it generates an interrupt. My current solution looks like the code below. Every time the timer overflows, a variable `counter_high` is incremented. The current counter value is read as a combination of `counter_high`  and the timer register.

```
volatile uint16_t counter_high = 0;

uint32_t get_counter(void)
{
    return (counter_high << 16) | timer->counter;
}

void timer_overflow(void)
{
    counter_high++;
}
```

This seems to work. However I have started to wonder what happens if the timer overflows while `get_counter()` is executed? I could get the old value of `counter_high` combined with the new value of `timer->counter` or vice versa.

Is there a best practice for preventing this problem?

Comment: you basically want to read low, then check for overflow. if overflow then adjust high and re-sample low and you should be safe.  or you can make low zero depending on which end of the function call you want to be the closest to the real time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read `counter_high` before and after reading `timer->counter`.  If the value read for `counter_high` does not change then you know that `timer->counter` did not rollover between the reads and therefore you can trust the value you read from `timer->counter`.

However if `counter_high` changed between the two reads then you know `timer->counter` rolled over sometime between the two reads.  This means you cannot trust the value you read from `timer->counter` because you don't know whether you read it before or after the rollover.  But now you know `timer->counter` just recently rolled over so you can read it again and know that it is not about to rollover a second time.

```
uint32_t get_counter(void)
{
    uint32_t first_counter_high = counter_high;
    uint32_t counter_low = timer->counter;
    uint32_t second_counter_high = counter_high;
    if (first_counter_high != second_counter_high)
    {
        counter_low = timer->counter;  // Read timer->counter again, after rollover.
    }
    return (second_counter_high << 16) | counter_low;
}
```